# Android Studio - Cannot find symbol class

Tags: android-studio, build.gradle

When I run my app, Android Studio notifies me some error in Gradle Build.

Could you help me understand how to fix this problem?

#### MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
DatabaseHelper myDb;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    addMarkers();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    LatLng ruvo = new LatLng(-45, 123);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(ruvo).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(ruvo));
}

public void onSearch(View view) {
    EditText textCity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textCity);
    String location = textCity.getText().toString();
    List<android.location.Address> addressList = null;

    if (location != null) {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
        try {
            addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        android.location.Address address = addressList.get(0);
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Marker pointed"));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    } else {
        textCity.setHint("Enter a valid city");
        //textCity.setTextColor();
    }

}

public void addMarkers() {
    ArrayList<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
    Cursor database = myDb.display();
        if (database.getCount()== 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Nothing to found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        database.moveToFirst();
        do {
            int latitude = (int) (database.getDouble(database.getColumnIndex("LAT")) * 1E6);
            int longitude = (int) (database.getDouble(database.getColumnIndex("LONG")) * 1E6);
            items.add(new OverlayItem(new GeoPoint(latitude, longitude)));
        } while (database.moveToNext());

}

}
```

#### build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 23
  buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.android.sqlite"
      minSdkVersion 16
      targetSdkVersion 23
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
    }
  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.2.0'
}
```

#### Error messages:

```
Error:(82, 19) error: cannot find symbol class OverlayItem
Error:(82, 54) error: cannot find symbol class OverlayItem
Error:(92, 31) error: cannot find symbol class OverlayItem
Error:(92, 47) error: cannot find symbol class GeoPoint
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.`

Comment: Try clean & build project